# StreamDensityPlot: Two legends instead of one

Tags: plotting, legending

**Bug found in Mathematica v12.0.0.0-MacOs 12.3-Monterey and fixed as late as v12.2.0-Win7-x64**

In Mathematica v12.0.0.0 I used the following code to create a stream-density plot.

'''

```
XYGradCLE2DCartes = {(2 x)/(3 (x^2 + y^2)^(2/3)), (2 y)/(
   3 (x^2 + y^2)^(2/3))};

Show[
 StreamDensityPlot[-XYGradCLE2DCartes, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", {0, 1}}, 
    LegendLabel -> Style["C", 20, FontFamily -> "MathJax_Math"], 
    LabelStyle -> 
     Directive[Black, 20, FontFamily -> "MathJax_Main"]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", {0, 1}}],
  FrameStyle -> {{{Thick, FontFamily -> "MathJax_Math"}, 
     Thick}, {{Thick, FontFamily -> "MathJax_Math"}, Thick}},
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
  FrameTicks -> {{{-1, 0, 1}, None}, {{-1, 0, 1}, None}},
  FrameTicksStyle -> 
   Directive[Black, 20, FontFamily -> "MathJax_Math"],
  PlotRangePadding -> 0,
  StreamStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.006], Red],
  StreamScale -> {Medium, 2.5, 
    0.03},(*The 3rd arguments seems to be controling the size of the \
arrows*)
  StreamPoints -> 20
  ],
 LabelStyle -> {24, GrayLevel[0]}
 ]
```

'''

I intended to have only one legend, but it prints two:

[image]

This problem was not present when I launched the code in  v13.0.0.0, where I got the following result

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with v13.0.1. Trying starting with `Clear["Global\`*"]` If that doesn't work, start with a fresh kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you getting just one legend?

Comment: Yes, just one legend.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, thank you very much. The plots above were created in Mathematica v 12.0.0.
Now that I have installed v13.0.0.0, the second legend is gone.

So I guess case closed.

Comment: I can also reproduce the issue using `V12`. `V13` works fine

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue in v12.2.0-Win7-x64. I get only one legend.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can be reported to WRI. After you get a response, please come back and update the page header with, possibly, the bugs tag.

Comment: I have updated the page header with a bugs tag, Hopefully I did it right.
Thank you all for the help Bob Hanlon, bmf, @Syed.

Comment: No issue in 12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 18, 2020), although v 12.0 reproduces the issue. In the future, please only put a minimal example here, it is enough to just do a StreamDensityPlot with PlotLegends->BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors",{0,1}}] to produce the issue.